# CSS last-child if more than 4 elements

Tags: html, css

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5parpxy/) - I'm trying to only get the last element to highlight ONLY if there is more than 4 containers within the wrapper. Is it possible to do this using css instead of JS

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">Container #1</div>
    <div class="container">Container #2</div>
    <div class="container">Container #3</div>
    <div class="container">Container #4</div>
    <div class="container">Container #5</div>
</div>

.wrapper div:nth-child(n+4):last-child() {
   background-color: gold;
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting output like this http://jsfiddle.net/q5parpxy/1/ ?

Comment: If you want more than 4 (not including 4), then you should use the rule `.wrapper div:nth-child(n+5):last-child()`

Comment: @Terry it's `:last-child` though

Comment: @misterManSam Oh yes, I stand corrected: `.wrapper div:nth-child(n+5):last-child`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. You can achieve this. You are almost there just some small correction.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/q5parpxy/4/

```
.wrapper div:nth-child(n+5):last-child {
   background-color: gold;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct syntax

```css
.wrapper div:nth-child(n+4):last-child {
   background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">Container #1</div>
    <div class="container">Container #2</div>
    <div class="container">Container #3</div>
    <div class="container">Container #4</div>
    <div class="container">Container #5</div>
</div>
```

`last-child` should be used without braces

Comment: the answer was already postet, why do you think you need to type in almost the same again??

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```css
.wrapper div:last-child:nth-child(n+5) {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">Container #1</div>
  <div class="container">Container #2</div>
  <div class="container">Container #3</div>
  <div class="container">Container #4</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">Container #1</div>
  <div class="container">Container #2</div>
  <div class="container">Container #3</div>
  <div class="container">Container #4</div>
  <div class="container">Container #5</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">Container #1</div>
  <div class="container">Container #2</div>
  <div class="container">Container #3</div>
  <div class="container">Container #4</div>
  <div class="container">Container #5</div>
  <div class="container">Container #6</div>
</div>
```